# How can I enable strict di mode in Angular unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm using karma and noticed that while running unit tests, I do not get the error

```
is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

And instead get the error.

```
Unknown provider
```

For artifacts that are missing dependency injection annotations.  However, this happens only when I am running unit tests against my minified code.  If I can turn on strict di, I would be able to "fail fast" during unit test runs on our unminified code, which provides our coverage reports.

*Edit*

There is a function `angular.mock.inject.strictDi(value:boolean)` which seems to enable strict DI mode but the function is undocumented.